# Unity : How to deal with many colliders or triggers at once?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In unity, We can deal with collisions and positions with trigger. However, I couldn't find any of information about dealing plural conditions of triggers or collider.

For example, if there is two balls connected with one cylinder, how should I have to control the state of Cylinder Which affected by two different balls.

- If ball A is black and ball B is white, than the connected cylinder
  is gray.
- If both A & B is black, cylinder is black.
- If both A & B is
  white, cylinder is white.

[image]

Comment: Keep a list of all objects that have entered the trigger through recording them in the `OnTriggerEnter()` event, then change the colour of the cylinder as needed once the required number of objects (in this case, 2) have entered that list. Try writing some code for this, and if you continually are unsuccessful in doing so, edit your question to include your attempt. At the moment, we don't have enough details on your circumstances to deduce a working solution.

Comment: Making a list for OntriggerEnter() is possible?? thank you I will search for the accessing the colliding objects. Thank you  so much~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the problem with a simple script like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TriggerScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject sphereA, sphereB;
    MeshRenderer meshA, meshB, meshC;
    Color colorA, colorB;

    void Awake() {
        meshA = sphereA.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        meshB = sphereB.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        meshC = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        colorA = meshA.material.color;
        colorB = meshB.material.color;
    }

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider other) {
        // Check which sphere is "other"
        if (other.gameObject == sphereA) {
            colorA = meshA.material.color;
        }
        if (other.gameObject == sphereB) {
            colorB = meshB.material.color;
        }

        // Check which are the spheres' colors and change cylinder color accordingly
        if (colorA == Color.black && colorB == Color.white ||
            colorA == Color.white && colorB == Color.black) {
            meshC.material.color = Color.gray;
        }
        else if (colorA == Color.black && colorB == Color.black) {
            meshC.material.color = Color.black;
        }
        else if (colorA == Color.white && colorB == Color.white) {
            meshC.material.color = Color.white;
        }
    }
}
```

Attach the script to the cylinder game object, give the spheres' references via Inspector and that's all. You can change `OnTriggerStay` to `OnTriggerEnter` based on what you want to accomplish ofc.
Remember that the spheres can have only the `Collider` component, but the cylinder must have a `Rigidbody` component too.

Comment: Thanks a lot~ haha

Comment: @TaeyeongHan you're welcome. If the answer is satisfactory, please do not forget to tag it as accepted. ;)

Comment: Sorry but can you tell me how to accept?? i will find it!

Comment: @TaeyeongHan just click on the checkmark that you can see on the top left of my answer, just under the down arrow.